# Why this method for function overloading in C works?

Tags: c, overloading

I've looked over some ways of doing it in C but i've only found for C99.

But i've come across the solution below, taken from [Lock Less](https://locklessinc.com/articles/overloading/).

The thing is, I don't quite understand how it works and would like know the fundamentals of what is going on there to be able to understand it more clearly.

I've fetched the web for a while and found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) about **__VA_ARGS__**, but that alone wasn't enough unfortunately.

I would really appreciate an explanation or some guidance about this matter, any kind of reference would help.

I've compiled this code with *GCC-5.4.1* with **-ansi** flag.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNT_PARMS2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _, ...) _
#define COUNT_PARMS(...)\
    COUNT_PARMS2(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

void count_overload1(int p1)
{
    printf("One param: %d\n", p1);
}

void count_overload2(double *p1, const char *p2)
{
    printf("Two params: %p (%f) %s\n", p1, *p1, p2);
}

void count_overload3(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    printf("Three params: %c %d %d\n", p1, p2, p3);
}

void count_overload_aux(int count, ...)
{
    va_list v;
    va_start(v, count);

    switch(count)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            int p1 = va_arg(v, int);
            count_overload1(p1);
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            double *p1 = va_arg(v, double *);
            const char *p2 = va_arg(v, const char *);
            count_overload2(p1, p2);
            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            int p1 = va_arg(v, int);
            int p2 = va_arg(v, int);
            int p3 = va_arg(v, int);
            count_overload3(p1, p2, p3);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            va_end(v);

            printf("Invalid arguments to function 'count_overload()'");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    va_end(v);
}
#define count_overload(...)\
    count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double d = 3.14;
    count_overload(1);
    count_overload(&d, "test");
    count_overload('a',2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
One param: 1
Two params: 0x7ffc0fbcdd30 (3.140000) test
Three params: a 2 3
```

Comment: This is not function overloading. This only _simulates_ function overloading to the developer writing the source code.

Comment: This looks the same to a developer as if `count_overload` were a variable argument function. You're just obscuring a `count` argument that's needed by the called function to know when it has to handle the extra arguments versus knowing this implicitly from the other given arguments. Other functions in C, such as `printf`, determine how many and type of arguments to access by what the format string contains. `printf` appears no less like an "overloaded" function than `count_overload`. Under the covers here, you are not overloading anything. It's just variable arguments.

Comment: And then there's the overhead in `count_overload_aux` before it gets around to actually calling the real function. All in all, this is something that you should never do in real code.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I totally understand that it is not a perfect function overload, but for a client implementation using a library that managed to do this, would feel like it is an actual overload, except for the part that there is no overload for equal amount of arguments differing only by the argument types.
And that is exactly what I would like to produce, because there might be slightly different ways to use the same function but in C it would require that each way had its own name.
An example would be a kind of constructor overload.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte: That's all fine and dandy, except for the fact that this can severely reduce, or even eliminate, compile-time type checking. So, unless everyone involved knows _exactly_ what's going on with the macro substitution and argument interpretation, you could be in for a real debugging treat.

Comment: If you don't care about compile-time type checking, then just use a printf-like interface, where the first parameter is a string that describes the following parameters. For example, `foo("dpi", 3.0, &x, 42)` where the "format" interpretation is `d` for double, `p` for pointer-to-int, and `i` for int. That's easier for a developer to understand than all the macro nonsense, it supports equal amount of arguments with different types, and it's neither more nor less safe than the macro solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break down the `COUNT_PARMS` and `COUNT_PARMS2` macros.  First `COUNT_PARMS`:

```
#define COUNT_PARMS(...)\
    COUNT_PARMS2(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Since the macro contains no named arguments, any parameters passsed to it are put in place of `__VA_ARGS__`.

So the following calls:

```
COUNT_PARMS(arg1)
COUNT_PARMS(arg1, arg2)
COUNT_PARMS(arg1, arg2, ,arg3)
```

Will expand to:

```
COUNT_PARMS2(arg1,   10,    9,  8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
COUNT_PARMS2(arg1, arg2,   10,  9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
COUNT_PARMS2(arg1, arg2, arg3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
                                                  // x
```

I spaced out the arguments so you can see which ones correspond to each other.  Make special note of the column marked `x`.  This is the number of parameters passed to `COUNT_PARMS`, and it's the 11th argument in each case.

Now let's look at `COUNT_PARMS2`:

```
#define COUNT_PARMS2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _, ...) _
```

There are 11 names arguments, plus `...` to account for any additional arguments.  The entire body of the macro is `_`, which is the name of the 11th argument.  So the purpose of this macro is to take 11 or more arguments and replace them with just the 11th argument.

Looking again at the definition of `COUNT_PARAMS`, it expands in such a way that it calls `COUNT_PARMS2` with the 11th parameter being the number of parameters passed to `COUNT_PARAMS`.  This is how the magic happens.

Now looking at the function calls in `main`:

```
count_overload(1);
count_overload(&d, "test");
count_overload('a',2,3);
```

These expand to this:

```
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS(1), 1);
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS(&d, "test"), &d, "test");
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS('a',2,3), 'a',2,3);
```

Then this:

```
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS2(1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), 1);
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS2(&d, "test", 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), &d, "test");
count_overload_aux(COUNT_PARMS2('a',2,3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), 'a',2,3);
```

Then this:

```
count_overload_aux(1, 1);
count_overload_aux(2, &d, "test");
count_overload_aux(3, 'a',2,3);
```

The end result is that you can call a function that takes a variable number of arguments without having to explicitly say how many there are.

Answer (score 2):

[dbush's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969032/1480131) explains what the macros are doing. I'd like to
expand on this and talk about the ellipsis `...` which is used here. You say
that reading about the variadic macros and `__VA_ARGS__` didn't help, so I
presume that you might not understand C ellipsis too well either.

In C a way to declare a function that takes an variable number of arguments is
to use the ellipsis `...`. A prime example of such a function is `printf`, which
can takes at least one parameter, but it accepts many more.

The prototype of `printf` is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

The `...` is used for declaring the ellipsis. Note that the `...` can only
appear at the end of the named arguments and it shouldn't be a register
variable, a function or an array type, hence:

```
void foo(...)
{
}
```

is invalid, the compiler would show you an error like this:

```
c.c:6:10: error: ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’
 void foo(...)
          ^~~
```

So, how do use this? You use [`va_list`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) defined in `stdarg.h`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

int sum(int num_of_values, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    // use the last named argument
    va_start(ap, num_of_values);

    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_values; ++i)
    {
        int v = va_arg(ap, int);
        s += v;
    }

    va_end(ap);

    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
}
```

which will output `The sum is: 15`.

So when your function has an ellipsis, you must first declare a variable of type
`va_list` and call `va_start` with that variable as the first argument and the
last named argument as the second argument.

Then you can fetch the values by using `va_arg(ap, <type>)`, where `<type>` is
the type of the value, in case of the example above, it would be `int`. Functions like
`printf` parse the format and use the conversion specifiers to get the correct
type. When `printf` founds an `%d`, it will do `va_arg(ap, int)`, if `%f` is
found it would do `va_arg(ap, float)` and if `%s` is found, it would do
`va_arg(ap, char*)` and so on. That's why `printf` has undefined behaviour when the format
and the arguments don't match, because a wrong type would be used in the
`va_arg` call which messes with subsequent calls of `va_arg`. At the end `va_end` must be called.

For a micro kernel that I had to write during my days in the university, I had
to implement these `va_*`-macros. I used the behaviour of the compiler that it
put all arguments in the stack frame, so my `va_start` calculated the address in
that stack of the next value after the last named argument. `va_arg` moved through the stack
based on `va_start`'s calculation plus an offset determined by the type while
also updating the `ap` variable with the last consumed argument. It was
tricky to get it to work, but at the end it worked on that system, however the same implementation
on a `x86_64` produces only garbage.

How exactly this is implemented for example
in the GCC compiler, I don't know, but I suspect that GCC does something
similar. I've checked the source code [`gcc/builtins.c`:4855](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.c#L4855) but as usual,
I find the GCC code to be very complicated to follow.